# Points symmetric location (informational question)

Tags: qgis

I am working with a huge data set and having plotted/imported them through the QGIS I see the following:

[image]

As one can notice, points are almost perfectly distributed which is not real, because points are representing car/people location.

I have doubts that QGIS doing that in order to show all points without overlapping.

Is it possible to see a reallocation while zooming on the map? (when I am zooming out the map, points are distributed in a real way)

Comment: Please state, at which zoom level the change occurs. Have you loaded the data in a vanilla project? Have you checked the styling tab? Have you exported the data to another software (e.g. Google Earth) and checked the distribution there?

Comment: @Erik Scale: 1:999,  No, I did not try

Comment: QGIS has two different renderer (Point displacement and Point cluster)  that modify how point are displayed depending on zoom level (and other user set parameters) you may check if one of these are used. But to get usefull answer you should edit your question with the data format and how you add it to your QGIS project

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the points are being displayed with the "point displacement" style, with these settings:

- Placement Method: Grid
- Displacement lines turned off (or set to transparent)
- Center symbol turned off (or set to 0% opacity)

This combination of settings would arrange points in a grid when their actual locations are too close together to show without overlap. I'm perplexed about how you got to this state without knowing it, because these are definitely not default settings. Perhaps the layer was saved with a default style.

Change the symbology type to "single symbol." (This is the normal default symbology type for points.) Now the points should show in their correct geographic distribution at every zoom level.